Nontriviality of generalised inverses of a nondecreasing function (corrected)
Given a function $f:[0,\infty[\,\rightarrow[0,\infty]$, its right inverse is defined as $$f^\top(t):=\sup\{s\geq0\mid f(s)\leq t\},$$ while its left inverse is defined as $$f^\bot(t):=\sup\{s\geq0\mid f(s)<t\}.$$ Now, let us assume that we are given a nondecreasing function $g:[0,\infty[\rightarrow[0,\infty]$ satisfying the "nontriviality" condition
$$\exists x_0>0\;\;\;\;\mathrm{such}\,\mathrm{that}\;\; \lim_{x\rightarrow^{+}x_0} g(x)<\infty.$$ Does it imply that $g^\top$ and $g^\bot$ are also "nontrivial" in the above sense?
Edit 1: Note that $g$ is not assumed to be continuous or strictly increasing at any part of its domain. The only assumption is finiteness of the right limit of a function at a single point of a domain. Apart from it, we know only that it is nondecreasing.
This question was marked as closed by an unknown person without any specification of a reason for this action, so I make an edit to bring it back.
In particular, if a function is continuous and strictly increasing at some range (as, for example, $t\mapsto\arctan(t)$, is), then the answer to my question is yes in a banal way, because at this range the right and the left inverse coincide with the usual notion of an inverse function. However, this not what I am asking about, since I have not stated that $g$ is continuous or strictly increasing on any part of its domain.
Edit 2: I realised that I made a mistake when I've typed in the "nontriviality" condition, and with this mistake it was an overkill for the question. Now it is corrected.

Hint: $g(t)=\arctan(t),.$

@KurtG. I do not see how this hint relates to the question, since $t\mapsto\arctan(t)$ has a domain at which it is continuous and strictly increasing, hence at this domain its left and right inverses are equal to its ordinary inverse, and so the generality of the class of the functions I am asking about is not meaningfully addressed by this example.

First of all: the question was not closed by a single person alone. There were six persons that voted to close it. $\arctan$ is bounded and does obviously satisfy that "nontriviality" condition but its inverse does not. Do you think it gets any better if we consider more general functions that only have right or left inverses? I did not deeply think that question through but it lacks context and own efforts.

@KurtG. Thanks for the reply. Thanks to this I've realised that I have typed not the condition I've indended for this question, but another condition, that was not the indended one (as can be seen from my first edit). Indeed, $\arctan(t)$ was the right hint for this wrong condition. Now, in the second edit, I have corrected the ``nontriviality'' condition to the correct one, that I am interested in.

It looks like that new nontriviality condition means that there is at least one point in the domain of $g$ at which is has a finite right limit.  Since you assume that $g$ is nondecreasing does this not hold trivially for all points?

I do not think so, since the function can jump to $\infty$ for $x>x_0$. (Also, it can have no left/right continuity properties.)

A monotone function has left and right limits. As soon as $g(x)<+\infty$ it must satisfy that nontriviality condition on $[0,x[,.$ In turn: if it does not satisfy the non triviality condition for any $x_0$ it must be identically infinite. In other words: all interesting functions satisfy that condition. Since their left/right inverses are also monotone they satisfy it as well.

And why specifically the left/right inverse of a function not identical to infinity is guaranteed to be a function not identical to infinity?

This will be my last jump as the old circus horse here: If $f^\top(t)=\infty$ for all $t\in[0,\infty[$ it means that
$f$ is bounded on $[0,\infty[$ by every $t\ge 0,.$ By your assumptions:
$f$ is $[0,\infty]$-valued. Then it must be identically zero.
One special case that drops out. The rest of the right inverses
is as I said.

Thank you for this answer, it adds an insight I was missing.

The "unknown" close voters are listed publicly on the timeline.

@peterwhy Thank you for this information, I wasn't aware of this before.
